# Using dplyr functions and data.table in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, dplyr

I am using arrange, filter and select in my shiny app to filter my dataset.
First I am arranging my dataset based on the column specified by the user. The I am filtering the rows as specified by the user and then I am selecting the relevant columns.

```
sorted<-reactive(
obstacle %>%
  arrange_(order, input$obs) %>%
  filter(Subgroup.Level == input$sublevel) %>%
  select(Economy, input$obs))
```

Using just arrange gave me an error that said :

Error: cannot arrange column of class 'function' at position 1

On searching a bit online I found that I could use the SE version arrange_. Using that I am getting the error:

Error: Can't convert a function to a quosure

I am fairly new to R so I am really confused as to what I should do now. Earlier I was using the subset function to filter the data and it worked but it was making my app really slow. Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: using the `arrange_` version is expecting a string input, as apposed to the `arrange` version that uses objects within the table. I suspect you want `arrange_("order", input$obs)` - note the quotes around the column name.

Comment: That's giving me the same error as earlier: cannot arrange column of class 'function' at position 1

Comment: is `order` the name of a column, or a variable?

Comment: Order is part of the arrange function it's telling it to order the data frame with respect to the column input$obs

Comment: in that case, you don't need `order` at all. The `arrange()` function just needs the column names to order on. So I think you should be using `arrange_(input$obs)`

Comment: i tried with `mtcars` as `mtcars %>%
  arrange(mpg, cyl) %>%
  filter(gear == 3) %>%
  select(vs, carb)` which seems to be working fine...

Comment: similarly, `mtcars %>% arrange_("mpg", "cyl")`

Comment: I removed the order the error now is: Error in filter_impl: Result must have length 5444, not 0

Comment: It works for the normal values but since I'm using variable input from the user, it's running into a problem.

Comment: It's giving me the output after giving the error, but again its very slow. I wanted to use dplyr to make it faster but that's not happened.

Comment: transform Your data to `data.table` and then use `dplyr`, it should make it faster

Comment: @Malvina_a, I did that but I have another problem now. Since data.table takes all values as char, my numeric values are not getting plotted. It says discrete values supplied to continuous scale. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: @Pooja i cannot reproduce Your Error (see the Answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example shiny App with working `dplyr` transformation and plot (as You have not supplied a reproducible example, neither the data, i have used `mtcars` dataset):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

ui= fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "obs", label= "Obs", 
                     choices= names(mtcars), 
                     selected= names(mtcars)[1],
                     multiple=F),
      selectizeInput(inputId= "sublevel", label= "Sublevel", 
                     choices= sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)), 
                     selected= sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1],
                     multiple=F)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab"),
      plotOutput('plot')
    )
  )
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  data <- data.table(mtcars)
  print(str(data))

  sorted <- reactive({data %>% arrange_(input$obs) %>% filter(cyl == input$sublevel) %>% select_("cyl", input$obs)})

  output$tab= renderTable(sorted())

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(sorted(), aes_string(x="cyl", y=input$obs)) + geom_point(size=5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As You can see i have transformed first the data into `data.table`, then arranged and filtered using `dplyr`,further i have used `str()` to check the column classes (and **they are correctly numeric even after using `data.table`**, as Your point was that they were transformed into `char` type) and plotted it without any problem.

Comment: Earlier I was reading the data using fread() but I'm following what you did and it works. Only thing is that it's still slow.

Comment: is it slow at `arrange` and `filter` from `dplyr`?

Comment: Yeah and I'm plotting a map so I have to merge my filtered  and arranged data every time and that also makes it slow.

Comment: I tried using the data.table function order() and [ to subset the data but because I have input$obs instead of a column name it doesn't work. It works fine when I try it out with some column name.

Comment: to sort with data.table use `input$obs` as a key, for example: `data <- data.table(mtcars, key=c(input$obs))`, then it will sort the data according to the selected column in `input$obs`